# awk to find the line number of complete match of a string

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I need to find the line number of a complete and exact match of a string :

Example :

```
stackflow
stack
stackflow123
stackflow 123
```

If the string value is "stackflow" I need the code to return 1 and ignore the rest as the lines are not an exact match.

I tried the below, but it needs slight adjustments to make it work only for the exact match while using variables :

```
awk -v x="$line" '$0~x {print NR}' file
```

Comment: Use `$0==x` maybe.

Comment: What if there is more than one such line? Should all matching line numbers be printed or only first of them?

Answer (score 0):

*If the string value is "stackflow" I need the code to return 1 and ignore the rest as the lines are not an exact match*:

```
$ line=stackflow 
$ awk -v s="$line" '$0==s{print NR;exit 1}' file
```

Output:

```
1
```

Exit value:

```
$ echo $?
1
```